# SQL join tables with placing null to not existing values

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, null, cross-join

I'm trying to find which market doesn't have which product according to visit date. 
In order to do this I thought if I give all products to all markets there will be `null` dates because there will be no visit for that product for the market. To see
all products in the market I wrote a query :

```
SELECT id, p.ProductName FROM atb_markets
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT StokAd FROM atb_products) p
```

and I got this kind of a view:

```
 MarketId   productName
    1         a
    1         b
    1         c
    1         d
    1         e
    1         f
    2         a
    2         b
    2         c
    2         d
    2         e
    .         .
    .         .
```

By the way these all are different tables (`atb_markets`, `atb_products`) and dates are saving on the `outformmobiledata` table. This table holds each record for the markets. `marketId`, `productId` and `date` is holding on this table (date information comes from mobile devices). Because of I need `productName` I need `atb_products` table also.

Finally I need this view by using these three tables. If I get `null` values I can know which products don't exists on a market.

And this is the view I need:

```
date        MarketId   productName
01.12.2013     1         a
11.12.2013     1         b
NULL           1         c
04.12.2013     1         d
20.12.2013     1         e
05.12.2013     1         f
06.12.2013     2         a
NULL           2         b
NULL           2         c
12.12.2013     2         d
NULL           2         e
.              .         .
.              .         .
```

**As you see in the second table `market_number1` never had product c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`LEFT OUTER JOIN`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for `outformmobiledata` table:

```
SELECT d.date, m.id, p.ProductName
  FROM atb_markets m
  CROSS JOIN atb_products p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN outformmobiledata d
    ON d.marketId = m.id
    AND d.productId = p.id
ORDER BY m.id, p.ProductName
```

Comment: THANKS!! That's what I exactly want. Thanks for your help @Rimas